# Finding column names of a data frame using $ operator

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to find the column names of a data frame using $ operator? I have written a function to plot x data and variable number of y data using plotly. I am working with a dataset with 20 columns. I need to subset a variable number of columns and plot using plotly. I wrote the following two functions:

```
subset_variable_cols()
```

for subsetting arbitrary number of columns from dataset

```
 subset_variable_cols <- function(df, ...){
      
      x <- list(...)
      
      sub <- subset(df, select = c(...))
      return(sub)
    }
```

and

```
 plotly_variable_y()
```

for plotting the variables specified by the user, where the first argument is x.

```
 plotly_variable_y <- function(vars){
  
     uu <- subset_variable_cols(df, vars)
    setDT(uu)   longDF <- melt(uu, id.vars = "Time")
     plot_ly(longDF, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", x = ~Time, y = ~value, split = ~variable) }
```

The data frame is as follows

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = rnorm(100), .... ,y20 = rnorm(100))
```

`plotly_variable_y(x, y1, y6, y10)` will plot `y1`, `y6` and `y10` in the y axis with common shared `x`

The issue is the names of the actual data frame that are quite big with tags, so I would like to keep them as it is.  I was trying to find an easy way to extract the names from df$y1, df$y6, df$y10, etc since the user can call the function easily using Rstudio's ability to autofill the names after typing 'df$'. Any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: In your example `df`, what are examples of the names you want to extract?

Comment: Instead of implying what your data frame may look like (ie, using ellipses), could you provide a workable example with desired outcome?

Comment: Are you saying that your `plotly_variable_y` function is parameterized using a certain data.frame's variable names, but it would be convenient for you to instead enter with autocomplete like `df$y1` (the name of a vector) and you would like that vector to be interpreted as a variable name `y1`?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question that includes the two functions that I wrote to subset an arbitrary number of columns from the data frame and the other to plot those variables using plotly()

Comment: @JonSpring The variable names are actually quite big with tags  - something like  "Pseudotsuga menziesii, tagID:76883y369"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(plotly); library(data.table)

plotly_variable_y <- function(...) {
  subset_variable_cols <- function(...) {
    x <- cbind.data.frame(...)
    setNames(x, gsub('.*\\$', '', names(x)))
  }
  uu <- subset_variable_cols(...)
  setDT(uu) 
  longDF <- melt(uu, id.vars="x")
  plot_ly(longDF, type="scatter", mode="lines", x=~x, y=~value, split=~variable) 
}

plotly_variable_y(df$x, df$y1, df$y2)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y1=rnorm(10), y2=rnorm(10), y20=rnorm(10))
```